# Suppressing Outlook Field Printing

Tags: c#, outlook

We have written an add-on for Outlook that files emails into our CRM system. Int he process of this, it saves the Outlook Message ID as a UserField on the Message itself.

eg.

```
currentUserProperty = Constants.APPLICATION_NAME + "EntryID";
mailItem.UserProperties.Add(currentUserProperty,
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText,
       Missing.Value,
       Missing.Value).Value = entryId;
```

Unfortunately, this is a HUUUGGEE number, much like:

**"00000000D502D779150E2F4580B1AADDF04ECDA6070097EF5A1237597748A4B4F9BFF540020800000006E9E4000068BB5B6DFC36924FAEC709A17D056583000002DE0E350000"**

The problem is that when the user prints the message off, Outlook insists on including this field (beneath the From/To) and because it has no spaces, cannot wrap the ID and compresses the A4 page until it can fit on horizontally. This produces teeny-tiny email printouts.

Is there any way I can correct this? I had thought of overwriting the field OriginalEntryID (which is the one causing the problem) with one delimited by spaces but I get an exception from the COM layer. My next stop is to try and suppress the output of this and other user-defined fields on Outlook stationary.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be able to help me:

http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=5071#postform

Answer (score 17):

You must use **.NET Reflection** to fix this (*as recommended by Microsoft Support*). Hopefully this will be fixed in future versions of the VSTO SDK.

#### Suppress Outlook User Field Printing

```
static void SuppressUserPropertyPrinting(Outlook.MailItem message)
{
    try
    {   // Late Binding in .NET: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302902
        Type userPropertyType;
        long dispidMember = 107;
        long ulPropPrintable = 0x4; // removes PDO_PRINT_SAVEAS
        string dispMemberName = String.Format("[DispID={0}]", dispidMember);
        object[] dispParams;

        if (message.UserProperties.Count == 0) return; // no props found (exit)

        // marks all user properties as suppressed
        foreach (Outlook.UserProperty userProperty in message.UserProperties.Cast<Outlook.UserProperty>())
        {
            if (userProperty == null) continue; // no prop found (go to next)
            userPropertyType = userProperty.GetType(); // user property type

            // Call IDispatch::Invoke to get the current flags
            object flags = userPropertyType.InvokeMember(dispMemberName, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, userProperty, null);
            long lFlags = long.Parse(flags.ToString()); // default is 45 - PDO_IS_CUSTOM|PDO_PRINT_SAVEAS|PDO_PRINT_SAVEAS_DEF (ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee415114.aspx)

            // Remove the hidden property Printable flag
            lFlags &= ~ulPropPrintable; // change to 41 - // PDO_IS_CUSTOM|PDO_PRINT_SAVEAS_DEF (ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee415114.aspx)

            // Place the new flags property into an argument array
            dispParams = new object[] { lFlags };

            // Call IDispatch::Invoke to set the current flags
            userPropertyType.InvokeMember(dispMemberName, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, userProperty, dispParams);
        }
    }
    catch { } // safely ignore if property suppression doesn't work
}
```